# Showing that a function is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{}
             x,  &x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
              0, &x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus\mathbb{Q}
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
Show that f is not continuous for $x\neq0$.

I'd like to know if my attempted solution is ok:

Let $x_0\neq0$ and $\delta\gt0$.
Since rational and irrational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, there exist $x_1\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x_2\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ so that $x_1,x_2\in U'(x_0,\delta)$. Let $\epsilon=\frac{|x_1|}{2}$. Then $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|x_1|>\epsilon$ and f is not continuous.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=x$ if $x\in\mathbb Q$?  Otherwise this is not well defined.

Comment: That was a mistake, sorry. Corrected now.

Comment: The flow could be improved.  You should define $\epsilon$ before ever mentioning $\delta$.  That's because non-continuity means there exists an $\epsilon$ such that $\forall$ $\delta>0$ etc...

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have the right idea, but the way you write it is not quite correct.

Suggested edits: Fix $x_0\neq 0$. Let $\epsilon=\frac{x_0}{2}$. For every $0<\delta$, there exists a rational number $x_1$ and an irrational number $x_2$ in $U(x_0,\delta)$, and $|x_1|>\frac{x_0}{2}$.

Then $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|x_1|>\frac{x_0}{2}=\epsilon$, which means $f$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The preimage of, say, $]1,2[$ definitely not open.